# Changing ImmutableJS nested object with List and return whole state (Redux)

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, immutability, immutable.js

My state is a nested Immutable thing:

```
const state = Map({ counter: 0, 
                    people: List([
                        Map({name: "John", age: 12, etc...}),
                        Map({name: "Jim", age: 13, etc...}),
                        Map({name: "Jack", age: 21, etc...})
                     ])
                  });
```

So I have a Map, which holds a counter and List of Maps. I have simplified things here, but say I want to change some properties of John in my reducer.

Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
    var newState = state
                .get('people') //get the list
                .get(action.payload.pos) //pos is an integer, & describes the position of the object in the List
                .set('name', action.payload.name)
                .set('age', action.payload.age);
```

My problem is that I don't know how to set properties in John **and get back the whole state**, - so I can return it in my reducer. Right now what I am getting back is only the very part I am changing.

A second problem is this very long way to write all of this down. I know that there is a syntax for nested structures, but I have a `List` here, which kind of breaks this, so I am a bit stuck.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you already had the index, but I think the technique in my example should still work . Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it seems valid, I will try it in a bit. (That's also why I deleted my comment almost immediately, because I then saw that your answer did not rely on finding the index this way.)

Comment: Ok :) Let me know if/how it works out!

Comment: Hey again. Just checking in so you don't forget. If my answer didn't solve your issue but you have since found a solution yourself, you can post your solution as an answer and (after 48h) accept your own answer (you get not points though, for obvious reasons). That will help the future readers of this. More info on self-answering: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.findIndex` to find the index to update (if you don't already have it), and then use the index in a [`.updateIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/updateIn) call, together with [`.merge`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/merge) to merge the old and the new values.

```js
const state = 
  new Immutable.Map({ 
    counter: 0, 
    people: new Immutable.List([
        new Immutable.Map({name: "John", age: 12, otherVal: 'a'}),
        new Immutable.Map({name: "Jim", age: 13, otherVal: 'b'}),
        new Immutable.Map({name: "Jack", age: 21, otherVal: 'c'})
     ])
  });
  
const newValues = { name: 'Jones', age: 100};

// find index to update
const indexToUpdate = state
  .get('people')
  .findIndex(person => person.get('name') == 'Jim');
// use .updateIn to perform a merge on the person of interest
const newState = 
  state.updateIn(
    ['people', indexToUpdate],
    person => person.merge(newValues)
  );
  
console.log(
  'new state is:\n', 
  JSON.stringify(newState.toJS(), null, 2)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.7.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```